# Memory Leak in Actionscript 3 Substring Handling

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, memory-leaks

I'm running the very begninning of a program I'm going to use for a text-based adventure, and it seems to be working very well, but I've noticed a severe slowdown in my program. I've been using trace(System.totalMemory); to discover the problem and there is a very linear increase in memory, about 500b-1kb per frame.

```
{
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);
function fl_EnterFrameHandler(event: Event): void {
    //this block sets up the blinking cursor
    var_x = var_x + 1;
    if (var_x > 18) {
        var_x = 0;
        if (str_cursor == " ") {
            str_cursor = "█";
        } else {
            str_cursor = " ";
        }
    }
    //Checking to see if a picture needs to be drawn or not
    if (picture != "") {
        fulltext = (picture + "\n\n" + responce + "\n\n" + ">>>" + user_input + str_cursor);
    } else {
        fulltext = (responce + "\n\n" + ">>>" + user_input + str_cursor);
    }
    //Setting the interval of the draw string
    uInt = setInterval(writeIt, 1);
    function writeIt() {
        if (!printed) {
            //Finding the substring of the draw string and assignign to the text field
            fl_TF.text = fulltext.substring(0, count);
            count += count_speed;
            if (count > fulltext.length) {
                clearInterval(uInt);
                //Stoping the print loop
                printed = true;
                count = 0;
            }
        } else {
            user_input = inputField.text;
            fl_TextToDisplay = fulltext;
            fl_TF.text = fl_TextToDisplay;
        }
    }
    if (printed) {
        user_input = inputField.text;
        fl_TextToDisplay = fulltext;
        fl_TF.text = fl_TextToDisplay;
        clearInterval(uInt);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find the leak, as I've traced all my variables involved to the console at different points.

You can find a screenshot of the program here: http://i.imgur.com/dSWLeD5.gif

Comment: Without having the full source code to test with, I have some suspicions about your calls to `setInterval` and whether or not `uInt` is definitely being cleared within each call to `fl_EnterFrameHandler`. It's possible that you have some runaway intervals that could be causing the leak.

Comment: Have you tried using Adobe Scout?  I agree with Marcela, it's likely your interval not being cleared.  It's not very wise to be using setInterval inside of an ENTER_FRAME handler - especially with an anonymous function.   What is the purpose of the interval?

Answer (score 1):

- You start the interval every frame. That means about 25 times a
  second. AND your delay of the interval is 1**ms**. Thats not possible to handle.
- You define all functions every frame.

Which Scope has uInt?

**Generally:**

- Don't use closures in enter-frame-handlers! There's no need. Define
  them outer of the handler.
- Don't use `setInterval` in AS3. There ist
  the `Timer`-Class. What do you want to do with this curios code?